# JS function name interferes with object property

Tags: javascript, function, scroll, reference

I'm trying to build a polyfill for getting the actual scrollposition.

```
function getScLPos() {
    if (self.pageXOffset) return self.pageXOffset;
    if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollLeft)
        return document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
    if (document.body.scrollLeft) return document.body.scrollLeft;
    return 0;
}
```

But as it goes through the same condition checking procedure every function call.
I wanted to optimize the function by assigning a function reference to a global variable when it is called for the first time. Afterwards it reads the global variable (containing the funtion) and executes the function, but actually it doesnt work. When i call `getScLPos()` it still returns a function.

How ca I make `getScLPos` return an integer value?

Edit: `typeof pageXOffset()` says "function".

```
var getScLCallback = null;

function getScLPos() {

    if (getScLCallback != null) {
        return getScLCallback();
    } else {
        if (self.pageXOffset) {
            getScLCallback = pageXOffset;

            //says "function() {...}" 
            console.log(getScLCallback());

            return getScLCallback();
        } else if { ... }
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}

function pageXOffset() {
    return self.pageXOffset;
}
```

Comment: instead of a global var, you could actually cache the return function on the function itself (all functions are objects which can have properties). In a sense this would keep your cached var on function level, and wouldn't pollute your global scope that much. So in a function, you could do `function testMe() { if (testMe.property) { return testMe.property; } testMe.property = 'assigment'; return testMe.Property; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually made it work by renaming the `pageXOffset` function to `pXOffset`.

`pageXOffset` actually interfered with `self.pageXOffset`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, function references exist in JavaScript. Functions are just objects. The thing you are doing wrong is you are assigning the **result** of the function to the variable, instead of assigning the **function** itself. To assign a function to a variable, simply use the function name, without the `()` at the end.

So, instead of:

```
getScLCallback = docScrollLeft();
```

do this:

```
getScLCallback = docScrollLeft;
```

Here is your updated code:

```
var getScLCallback = null;

function getScLPos() {

    if (getScLCallback != null) {
        return getScLCallback();
    } else {
        if (self.pageXOffset) {
            // REMOVED the parentheses
            getScLCallback = pageXOffset;

            //says "function() {...}" 
            console.log(getScLCallback());

            return getScLCallback();
        } else if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollLeft) {
            // REMOVED the parentheses
            getScLCallback = docScrollLeft;
            return getScLCallback();
        } else if (document.body.scrollLeft) {
            // REMOVED the parentheses
            getScLCallback = bodyScrollLeft;
            return getScLCallback();
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}

function pageXOffset() {
    return self.pageXOffset;
}
function docScrollLeft() {
    return document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
}
function bodyScrollLeft() {
    return document.body.scrollLeft;
}
```

Comment: thanks, but considered this before... changed the function calls to references, but it didnt change anything...

Comment: You forgot the pageXOffset (to remove the ()). Also, if you then return it with (), then, i don't really see the use for it (it's still called on return)

Comment: Thanks @Icepickle, updated to include pageXOffset. The point of assigning it is because the OP has a check to see if it has already been assigned at the top.

Comment: @JohnJohnson So, what exactly are you trying to do? Your question is a bit unclear. What do you want `getScLPos()` to return?

Comment: I want it to return the actual ScrollLeft position.

Comment: ...by assigning a function to a global variable and later calling this global var

Comment: This code assigns the function to `getScLCallback`, and then returns the value of either `self.pageXOffset`, `document.documentElement.scrollLeft`, or `document.body.scrollLeft` (whichever one doesn't have a value of `0`). Have you tested this code along with also checking the values of those three properties? When you did this test, what was the actual output, and what was the expected output?

Comment: When I run it, it returns an integer. I have not found an easy way to test if it is returning the correct integer, however. But that is a different issue then you said you are having in the original question.

Comment: @forgivenson i just checked the return value via "typeof pageXOffset()" and it says "function" but pageXOffset returns an integer.

Comment: @JohnJohnson Your code must be different than what I posted, because typeof pageXOffset() returns number for me.

Comment: It may because you have another browser? Made it work, wrote it in the question.